# How to scrape content using HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, html

I'm completely newbie to HTML agility pack, how can I grab those contents(proxy) using HTML agility pack in C#.

**My code :**

```
string url = "http://www.proxybase.de/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@border='0' and @cellspacing='0' and @cellpadding='0']");

        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    string s = item.InnerText;
                    listView1.Items.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing found");
        }
```

**The HTML will look likes ...**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
   <tr>...</tr> //Ignore first one
   <tr>
     <td>...</td>
     <td style="padding-left:5px;border-left;1px solid #999;"> 123.45.678.90:80  </td>
     <td style="padding-left:5px;border-left;1px solid #999;">...</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

*UPDATED* :

> How can I use SelectSingleNode to select table data with index array ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to store the website info, such as ip address etc into a file or a database

You are almost there if the above is true:
This should solve it:

```
    string url = "http://www.proxybase.de/";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@style='padding-left:5px;border-left;1px solid #999;'"))
    {
        String s =  HtmlNode.InnerText;
        //Now the IP address is stored in s.
        //You can either put it in a file/database or a webpage :)
    }
```

Comment: Fixed a typo in your example. It should be `//td` instead of `//tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        hw.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
        hw.PreRequest = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(p.ProxyOnPreRequest); // this is proxy request
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(openUrl);

    public bool ProxyOnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("203.189.134.17:80");
        request.Proxy = myProxy;
        return true; // ok, go on
    }
```